# Is it possible to block sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics, noise

Is it possible to block/eliminate particular noise sounds with artificially generated sound waves or any other ways?

Comment: Start with the Wikipedia article [Active noise control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control). It is how some noise cancelling headphones work.

Comment: In the "any other ways" category a vacuum blocks sounds waves, as the classic "alarm clock in a bell jar with vacuum pump" experiment demonstrates.